# Fire retardant spray on cedar fence

Tags: fence, fireproof

I have a cedar fence stained with ready seal, an oil based stain. The end posts go pretty close to the house as expected.

I am putting a shed up, to store flamables and such, and I have an electrical circuit for swimming pool attached to fence post.

In the event of something catching the fence on fire, id imagine itd work its way to the home and catch the house.

What can be used to retard the fire without ruining the looks of the fence? Like some sort of clear drying spray?

I was looking at this:

No-Burn Original Fire Retardant [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B003M8G39E/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_apa_FetuAbFQ70D2S](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003M8G39E)

But looks like some people complain of white resdue showing up when dried.

Comment: If worried about fire from the paints a metal paint cabinet or cabinets should be used. If worried about an electrical fire is the amount or type of paint make this a hazardous location. If this is the case proper types of conduit and electrical enclosures would be required.

Comment: @EdBeal Thanks for the reply Ed. Good idea on the cabinet. Electrical on fence is up to code and enclosed. I was just thinking about any unforeseen events. Like, we do plug in lighting on the fence as well for the pool or Christmas lighting in a small area. I may just be a bit on the extreme side of cautiousness, but I always think about if the cedar fence ever caught fire (however that may occur), how if not attended to in time, it's bound to catch the house. I was hoping for some sort of clear spray (without taking away aesthetics of the fence) to just spray on the pickets near the house.

Comment: I would not expect a fence to catch fire easily, and not to spread easily either, especially if there is distance between the pickets. What is the exterior material of your house? If it is brick, then no worries. I also wouldn't worry if it was fiber cement siding. I wouldn't want vinyl or old Masonite siding however.